# URL Encode - oauth_signature

Tags: oauth, dropbox-api

I have successfully setup the oauth authentication to access my dropbox using sharpbox.  Sharpbox is an open source "front end" that handles the nuts and bolts of the process.  Using it i can return file info in a particular folder in my account.

I bind the filename and a generated URI to a gridview in a VS 2010 web app.  I have a hyperlink with the text set to name and the DataNavigateUrlFields to the unique URL.  It works great IF there is no "+" character in the oauth_signature part of the url string.  If the plus is there, it returns "{"error": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string:"

Thanks for your consideration.

---

Thank you for your help, here is my code

```
Public Sub MakeURL()
    dbOpen()
    Dim myfolder As ICloudDirectoryEntry = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/DIR/SUBDIR/")
    Filename = Filename & "_POID_" & poid & ".pdf"
    pdfurl = dropBoxStorage.GetFileSystemObjectUrl(Filename, myfolder).ToString
    dbClose()
    pdfurl = pdfurl.Replace("+", "%2B")
    Response.Redirect(pdfurl)
     End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try URL Encoding the +?  Also, you should really post some code so the community can better answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth 1 Signature uses Percent Encoding (See [RFC 5849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849)). The specification clearly states that a space   should not be encoded to a `+`, instead it should be encoded with `%20`. Replace your `+` with `%20`.

Comment: Public Sub MakeURL()
        dbOpen()
        Dim myfolder As ICloudDirectoryEntry = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/DIR/SUBDIR/" & Vendor)
        Filename = Filename & "_POID_" & poid & ".pdf"
        pdfurl = dropBoxStorage.GetFileSystemObjectUrl(Filename, myfolder).ToString
        dbClose()
        pdfurl = pdfurl.Replace("+", "%2B")
        Response.Redirect(pdfurl)
    End Sub

Comment: @jimmy6509, if this solved your problem, accept the answer by clicking on the check mark, underneath the score, on the left of the answer section.

Comment: What other differences does the Oauth Percent encode have with regular URL Encoding? I'm having a hard time finding where it spells out that certain chars do not map to their base 16 equivalent.

Comment: Well, besides that HTTP URL Encoding converts a space into a `"+`, I don't forsee any further issues. What issues exactly are you experiencing?